# How would I find the values of $x$ and $y$ for which $A^2=A$

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, matrices, algebra-precalculus

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}x&-3\\ y&3\end{pmatrix}$$

$A $ is the matrix above.

Comment: Hi, what have you tried? where do you get stuck? Also, can you tell us a bit about what do you know currently so that we can help you at the right level?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Calculate $A^2$

$$\begin{bmatrix}x&-3\\ y&3\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x&-3\\ y&3\end{bmatrix}$$

$$=\begin{bmatrix}x^2-3y&-3x-9\\ xy+3y&-3y+9\end{bmatrix}$$

Then solve

$$x^2-3y=x$$

$$-3x-9=-3$$

$$xy+3y=y$$

$$-3y+9=3$$